# Xamarin IOS hide the search bar icon based on IsFocused property in custom renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I wanted to hide the search bar icon in IOS using custom SearchBarRenderer based on the IsFocused property. How can I achieve this?

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (Element == null || Control == null)
                return;

            var element = Element as CustomSearchBar;

            if (element.IsFocused)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Custom Renderer** to realize it , code as follow .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSearchBar), typeof(CustomSearchBarRenderer))]
namespace App15.iOS
{
    public class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        UIImage searchImg;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            searchImg = Control.GetImageForSearchBarIcon(UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.OnEditingStarted -= Control_OnEditingStarted;
                Control.OnEditingStopped -= Control_OnEditingStopped;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (null != Control)
                {
                    Control.OnEditingStarted += Control_OnEditingStarted;
                    Control.OnEditingStopped += Control_OnEditingStopped;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Control_OnEditingStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var searchBar = sender as UISearchBar;
            searchBar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(searchImg, UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
        }

        private void Control_OnEditingStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var searchBar = sender as UISearchBar;
            searchBar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(new UIImage(), UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: App15 is namespace in my local project.

As document **[Introduction to Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction)** of effects said , you also can refer to this document [Creating an Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating#ios-project) to use Effect to realize it ,because it no need to use Custom Renderer to do that .

Sample of Effects as follow:

Creating **SearchBarEffects** ：

```
public class SearchBarEffects : RoutingEffect
{
    public SearchBarEffects() : base($"MyCompany.{nameof(SearchBarEffects)}")
    {

    }
}
```

Using in **Xaml** :

```
// here is custom renderer
<local:CustomSearchBar Placeholder="renderer input"/> 
// here is custom effect
<SearchBar Placeholder="effect input">
    <SearchBar.Effects>
        <local:SearchBarEffects />
    </SearchBar.Effects>
</SearchBar>
```

Creating **SearchBarEffect** in iOS solution :

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(App15.iOS.SearchBarEffect), "SearchBarEffects")]
namespace App15.iOS
{
    public class SearchBarEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        UIImage searchImg;
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            searchImg = ((UISearchBar)Control).GetImageForSearchBarIcon(UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
            ((UISearchBar)Control).OnEditingStarted += SearchBar_OnEditingStarted;
            ((UISearchBar)Control).OnEditingStopped += SearchBar_OnEditingStopped;
        }

        private void SearchBar_OnEditingStopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var searchBar = sender as UISearchBar;
            searchBar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(searchImg, UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
        }

        private void SearchBar_OnEditingStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var searchBar = sender as UISearchBar;
            searchBar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(new UIImage(), UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            ((UISearchBar)Control).OnEditingStarted -= SearchBar_OnEditingStarted;
            ((UISearchBar)Control).OnEditingStopped -= SearchBar_OnEditingStopped;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally ,showing the effect by two ways . Up is Effect's , down is Renderer's .

[image]

Comment: I was able to achieve this by using the custom renderer. What went right for Junior Jiang - MSFT in custom render was providing new UIImage() for SetImageforSearchBarIcon method. In @ iSpain17 initial answer for custom rederer, he was providing null for SetImageforSearchBarIcon method so it did not work and later @ iSpain17 updated his answer for using PlatformEffect. Thank you both @ iSpain17 and Junior Jiang - MSFT for helping me for resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Personal note - there is no need to use a Custom Renderer for this, an effect is more than enough - I tested with Effect, not with custom renderer. On how to create Effects, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/creating)

`this.Control` will be a `UISearchBar` **if you only add this effect to `<SearchBar>` elements.**

So you can do this (based on [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/1624330-setimage) and [Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uisearchbar.setimageforsearchbaricon?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) documentation):

**iOS implementation of effect:**

```
public class NoSearchIconEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    UIImage defaultIcon = null;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var searchBar = this.Control as UISearchBar;
        defaultIcon = defaultIcon ?? searchBar.GetImageForSearchBarIcon(UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal); //This will save the default icon

        searchBar.OnEditingStarted += delegate
        {
            searchBar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(new UIImage(), UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
        };

        searchBar.OnEditingStopped += delegate
        {
            searchBar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(defaultIcon, UISearchBarIcon.Search, UIControlState.Normal);
        };
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Spain17. I have put this code in to OnElementChanged method. But it still shows the search icon.

Comment: It seems there is no state for editing the field, so you must work with the events. See my edit.

Comment: (I missed this part in the documentation for iOS: `Valid states are normal and disabled.`)

Comment: Hi @Spain17. Still I am unable to remove the default image using custom renderer with the newely priveded code. How can I achieve this using effects?

Comment: I added my full, tested code. But on how to create Effects (in case you aren't familiar with them), refer to the documentation I also linked above.